# Display data in datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have to make a DataGridView, or a DataGrid, or a Table, or something to show data in it, like this:

```
header: country   city         language
        usa       washington   eng
        germany   berlin       ger
        italy     rome         ita
```

I tried this:

```
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() 
    {Width=100, HeaderText ="ColumName1", CellTemplate 
        = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() {Width=100, HeaderText = 
    "ColumName2", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() {Width=100, HeaderText = 
    "ColumName3", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });



dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());

dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value= "asdasd";
dgv.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "asdasd";
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "asdasd";
```

There are no build errors, and when it starts, it is shown only the grid dimensions in the top left corner, and it's empty.

Comment: DataGridView is not WPF

Comment: how its not? i just wrote it, and it was there? Besides, what do u suggest?

Comment: You have a Windows Forms project not a WPF project... So I suggest that your wpf tag for this question is wrong. Then I can post an answer to show how to make it work in this simple case.

Answer (score 0):

if you have static data, you could use a Grid and do everything in XAML.

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="alöskdjf"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="alöskdjf"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBlock Text="alöskdjf"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="alöskdjf"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
```

if you need something more advanced you should really google for the MVVM Pattern and get your self familiar with Bindings. (There are tons of tutorials on the web).
But as you don't want to google... here is a example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--Set the items source to the DataRows Property of your DataContext (MyViewModel1)-->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataRows}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column A" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column B" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column C" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column D" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //create a new viewModel
            MyViewModel1 dataContext = new MyViewModel1();
            dataContext.DataRows = new List<MyDataRow1>();


            //create the datarows (you have to read your file here instead of adding 10 rows ;-)
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dataContext.DataRows.Add( new MyDataRow1() { A = "öasldkfj" , B="aösldkfj", C="sdkljgfskn", D="asdfasdf"});
            }

            DataContext = dataContext;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the ViewModel it provides Data data you can bind to from the UI
    /// </summary>
    public class MyViewModel1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the data rows.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The data rows.</value>
        public List<MyDataRow1> DataRows { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDataRow1
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: its just an example for the data...i got a whole file to take data from and to fill the table....what would be the best way?

Comment: I edited my answer and have provided a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Windows Forms Application. From there you can configure the DataGridView's columns in the designer.

This is how to set a row cell from code (as per your simple example)

```
 dgv.Rows.Add();
 dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "sdfs";
```